# Number to the exponent divided by exponent value

Tags: fractions

Can someone explain including working out how to solve this?

$$\dfrac{5^x}{x} = 79.85957$$

I know that the answer is $x = 3.5$, but how does one normalise the equation so that the x is on one side?

Comment: This is called a [transcendental equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation). They are solved by approximations only.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė There's no evidence that *each* transcendental equation could not be solved out *explicitly*. And we should point out what is *explicit*, say, the finite composition of addition, subtraction, multiplying, division and take logarithm, take exponent, and a list of constants (e.g. $1$, $i$, $\pi$, $e$, $\gamma$).

Comment: Notice the equation $e^x=3$ has no explicit solution in terms of algebraic operations (this excludes the logarithm). However, once we invent the log function then we have an *explicit* solution $\ln 3$. What exactly constitutes an *explicit* solution depends on the universe of allowed functions. Apparently, if we include the Lambert W function then there is an explicit solution. With this understanding the distinction between solving $e^x=3$ and the $5^x/x=79$ is removed. You can argue the natural log is more natural! But, others argue to include Lambert in our lexicon of basic functions.

Answer (score 4):

See here for a [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194267/solve-the-equation-2x-1-x). We can solve the equation in terms of the Lambert W function,

$$ \frac{5^x}{x}=c \Rightarrow \frac{ {\rm e}^{x \ln(5)} }{x} = c \Rightarrow \frac{ {\rm e}^{z } }{z} = \frac{c}{\ln(5)}\,, $$

where $z=x\ln(5)$. The last equation has the solution 
$$ z= -\operatorname{LambertW} \left( -{\frac {\ln  \left( 5 \right) }{c}} \right) \,,$$

where the Lambert W function is the solution of the equation $ y{\rm e}^{y}=x \,. $

Substituting $z = x \ln(5)$ and $c=79.85957$ gives the two real solutions

$$ x_1 = -\frac{1}{\ln(5)} \operatorname{LambertW}_{-1} \left( -{\frac {\ln  \left( 5 \right) }{79.85957}} \right) = 3.499999994 $$
and

$$ x_2 = -\frac{1}{\ln(5)}\operatorname{LambertW}_{0} \left( -{\frac {\ln  \left( 5 \right) }{79.85957}} \right) = 0.01278225404 \,.  $$

Comment: maybe I should put a section in my precalculus materials about this... I'm sure the students would appreciate it.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook: I believe it is a very good idea.