# Solve $x^x = a$ for known $a$?

Tags: numerical-methods

For example if you have  $x^x = 2$, can you express $x$ as a numerical expression containing only the addition, multiplication and exponentiation operators?

Comment: [Not really](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194267/solve-the-equation-2x-1-x).

Comment: The solution of your equation is $\frac{\ln(a)}{W(\ln(a))},$ where $W$ is the Lambert $W$-function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked at problems like this once and found the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). It is not the addition, multiplication and exponential operators you have asked for. I can't see how you would do that since we get the exact answer as follows:

$x\exp(x)=y \iff x=W(y)$

$x^x=2$

$x \log x=\log 2$

$(\log x)\exp(\log x)  = \log 2$

$x=\exp(W(\log 2))$

But 
$\log(2)=W(\log 2)\exp(W(\log 2))=W(\log 2)x$

$x=\frac{\log 2}{W(\log 2)}$

Comment: I don't really know this function but is there a method to evaluate this at a point? I mean if it has a simple taylor expansion then I guess we _can_ express it using basic operations.

Comment: From the Wikipedia page $W_0 (x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-n)^{n-1}}{n!}\ x^n = x - x^2 + \frac{3}{2}x^3 - \frac{8}{3}x^4 + \frac{125}{24}x^5 - \cdots$