# Does $z^i=i^z$ have any solutions, beside $z=i$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Does this equation have any solutions:

> $$\large{z^i=i^z}$$

Putting polar form of $z$ is better for LHS, But rectangular form is suitable for RHS !
What to do? Thanks!

Comment: Certainly $z=i$ is one solution.

Comment: Please define $i^z$ (or basically $\log(i)$).

Comment: I think general solutions of this equation are represented as [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194267/solve-the-equation-2x-1-x).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$$
\frac1z\log\left(\frac1z\right)=\frac1i\log\left(\frac1i\right)=-\frac\pi2
$$
Thus, there are many solutions, one for each branch of the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function):
$$
z=e^{-\mathrm{W}\left(-\pi/2\right)}
$$
One solution is `Exp[-LambertW[0,-Pi/2]]` which is `-i`.

Another is `Exp[-LambertW[-1,-Pi/2]]` which is `i`.

However, another is `N[Exp[-LambertW[1,-Pi/2]],20]` which is

`1.0213233161306520062 - 4.8683538060775645979 i`

Of course, the value of $z^i$ depends on which branch of $\log(z)$ is used. In the computation above, I have taken $\log(i)=\pi i/2$, so we have a clear definition of
$$
i^z=e^{\pi iz/2}
$$
However, $\log(z)$ is determined only mod $2\pi i$ and that affects $z^i$ by a factor of $e^{2\pi k}$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

For example, for $z=1.0213233161306520062-4.8683538060775645979\,i$, we use $\log(z)=1.60429091344801115852-7.64719227612459292313\,i$.

Answer (score 9):

$$i\times \ln(z)=z\times \ln(i)$$ Because $\ln(i)=\frac{1}{2}i\pi$ you have:
$\ln(z)=-\frac{1}{2}z\pi$ so, $z=-i$