# Invert this function $y=(1-x)e^{-x}$

Tags: calculus, mathematical-modeling

Consider the fucntion $f:\mathcal{R}\rightarrow \mathcal{R}$ given by the rule

$
f(x)=(1-x)e^{-x}
$

Now I want to invert this function(not just for fun but I have a data that seems to fit this form). I could see that $x$ can' be isolated. Taking the log on both sides doesn't help and I have tried other possibilities. So I tried the following. Using Taylor expansion $e^{-x}=1-x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}+...$
Now
$
f(x)=(1-x)(1-x-\frac{x^{2}}{2})=-\frac{1}{2}x^{3}+\frac{3}{2}x^{2}-2x+1
$

Now I could solve the cubic equation and solve for $x$. But this looks ugly and I don't know how good of an approximation it is. I was looking for possible suggestions to glean some information or write approximately a reasonable function for $x$ in terms of $y$ . Thank you

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194267/solve-the-equation-2x-1-x) for the technique.

Answer (score 4):

Here is mine ...
$$
y = (1-x)\exp(-x)
\\
\mathrm{e}y=(1-x)\exp(1-x)
\\
W(\mathrm{e}y) = 1-x
\\
x = 1-W(\mathrm{e}y)
$$

Maybe Arthur typed something wrong.

Comment: Yes, I missed the sign in the exponent of the original function. Will correct.

Comment: GEdgar, thanks for the quick reply. So I guess the best will be to compute W(ey) numerically and settle for that.

Answer (score 3):

According to [WolframAlpha](http://tinyurl.com/qj4jhcf), the answer is $1-W\left(ey\right)$, where $W$ is the (main branch of the) [Lambert W-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), which is defined as the inverse of the function $y =x e^x$. So I suspect there is no simple expression for the function you're after.

Comment: Thank you Arthur for the quick reply.

Comment: No need to say "main branch" ... the original function is not one-to-one, so we might as well use both branches.  And if you don't insist on a real function, you could use all the other branches, too.