# Real solution to a complex equation

Tags: complex-analysis

I have some trouble solving this equation. Let $a\in\mathbb R$, $a>1$. I want to show that there is a unique solution of

$ze^{a-z} = 1$,

with $|z|<1$ and that this solution is real and positive.

It is easy to prove the existence part of this problem. Indeed, taking log on both side, we get $\log x + a -x = 0$. However,  $\log 1 + a-1>0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} \log x + a- x < 0$. Thus, by the mean value theorem, there is a positive real solution. How can one show that this is the unique solution in the unit disk? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can get a solution in terms of Lambert W function. See my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194267/solve-the-equation-2x-1-x).

Comment: Thanks! I did not know Lambert W functions.

Comment: You are welcome. Your problem is a special case of the [problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217254/apparently-cannot-be-solved-using-logarithms/217262#217262).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $f(z) = ze^{a - z}$, $g(z) = -1$. Then for $z$ on the boundary of the disk,

$$|f(z)| = |z| |e^{a - z}| = |e^{a - z}| = exp({\Re(a - z)}) > 1 = |g(z)|$$

where the last inequality follows from the fact that $a > 1$. Hence by Rouche's Theorem, $f + g$ and $f$ have the same number of zeros in the disk, and $f$ clearly has a unique zero at $0$.

Comment: I am not sure I see the first inequality, since $|z|<1$.

Comment: @Gary The setup for Rouche requires the estimate to hold on the boundary of the disk, and $\partial \mathbb{D} = \{z : |z| = 1\}$.

Comment: I see! Thanks, this is a really good proof!