# How many solutions has $x^\alpha =\ln x$?

Tags: real-analysis

I have to determine the number of *real* solutions of $x^\alpha = \ln  x$ on varying of $\alpha > 0$.

How would you proceed?

Comment: You can have a solution in terms of Lambert W function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hints:

$$f(x):=x^\alpha-\log x\implies f'(x)=\alpha x^{\alpha-1}-\frac1x\ge0\iff\alpha x^\alpha\ge1\iff$$

$$\iff x\ge\frac1{\alpha^{1/\alpha}}\;\;\;\text{(we have}\;\;x,\alpha>0)$$

We thus see $\;f(x)\;$ is monotone descending for $\;x< \alpha^{-1/\alpha}\;$ and zero or ascending otherwise, thus

$$f\left(\alpha^{-1/\alpha}\right)=\frac1\alpha+\log\alpha$$

Observe though that

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=+\infty\;,\;\;\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=+\infty\;,\;\;\text{so:}$$

If the above value is positive there are zero solutions, if it is zero...etc.

Answer (score 3):

For $\alpha>0$, you can see that $g(x)=x^\alpha-lnx$ is a continuous function in $(0,\infty)$. By taking a derivative you can see that the function has one minimum which is $\frac{1}{\alpha}(1+\ln(\alpha))$. Now if minimum is negative, it has two real root, if it is positive there is no root and for zero-minimum there is one root and it is the minimum point. $\alpha=\frac{1}{e}$ is the point below which there is two roots.

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot! I have accepted another answer ONLY because it is as complete as yours and it was given some seconds before.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution

> $$\large {{\rm e}^{-{\frac {{W_k} ( -\alpha ) }{\alpha}}}}. $$

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194267/solve-the-equation-2x-1-x) for related problem.