# Solve the exponential equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the number of roots to $e^x = ax^2$ for all values of $a$. (x is real and so is $a$). I have tried some things but I am stuck.

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you have tried?

Comment: @Henrik just basic things like applying log on each side but I dont get anywhere.

Comment: These sort of equations are in general hard to solve. Often there isn't a closed form of the solution.
A possible numerical strategy is to assume that one solution is close to 1. So you can expand $e^{x}$ in a Taylor series around 0. $e^{x} \approx 1+x+0.5x^2$.

Comment: One thing that should be clear is that for $a \leq 0$, there are no roots. So you can at least focus on the case of $a>0$.

Comment: Easy enough with calculus, since they just want a count of the solutions $x.$ Without calculus, no.

Comment: See [the technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571398/exact-solution-for-logarithmic-equation/571431#571431).

Answer (score 2):

For $a>0$ the roots can be expressed in terms of Lambert $W$ function:

\begin{align}
a x^2&=\exp(x) \\
x^2\exp(-x)&=\frac{1}{a} \\
x\exp(-\frac{x}{2})&=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \\
-\frac{x}{2}\exp(-\frac{x}{2})&=\mp\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}} \\
-\frac{x}{2}&=\mathrm{W}\left( \mp\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}} \right)\\
x&=-2\mathrm{W}\left( \mp\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}} \right)
\end{align}

So, $\forall a>0$ there is always one negative real root 
$x_1=-2\mathrm{W_0}\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}} \right)$.
And since the Lambert $W(u)$ function has two real branches
for $-\exp(-1)<u<0$, it would be two more (positive) real roots (three total):

\begin{align}
x_2&=-2\mathrm{W_0}\left(-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}} \right), \\
x_3&=-2\mathrm{W_{-1}}\left(-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}} \right)
\end{align}
for $a>\exp(2)/4$.

Also, when $a=\exp(2)/4$ then $x_2=x_3$ and there are two real roots total.

Summarizing, the number $n$ of real roots to $\exp(x) = a x^2$:
\begin{align}
n&=
\begin{cases}
0,\quad a\le0 \\
1,\quad 0<a<\exp(2)/4 \\
2,\quad a=\exp(2)/4 \\
3,\quad a>\exp(2)/4 \\
\end{cases}.
\end{align}

[image]

Comment: +1, but you left out the answer for $a\le 0$ and $0<a\le exp(2)/4$. I know these are obvious, but they should be stated.

Comment: @Rory Daulton: Thanks, summary added.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are looking for the roots over the whole real line. Note that
$f(x)=e^x-ax^2$ is a continuous function on its domain but more importantly that the domain is a connected set. Does it sound like  Intermediate value theorem?