# Solving an equation without product log function (Lambert's W function).

Tags: analysis

Let $x=1+y\log(x)$. How do we solve this equation for $x$? I know that $x$ can be represented in terms of the product log function (or the Lambert's W function) of $y$. My question is, can we solve it without the help of this product log function?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Note that, $x=1$ is a solution.

Comment: Yes, of course. I actually want to know how do you write $x$ in terms of $y$ without the Lambert's W function? Thanks anyway.

Comment: See the technique in my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194267/solve-the-equation-2x-1-x) which may help you to manipulate your problem.

Comment: you are very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

> *I actually want to know how do you write x  in terms of y  without the [Lambert's W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).*

The function $y(x)=\dfrac{x-1}{\ln x}$ possesses no elementary [inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function).

Comment: You're welcome, Nicole. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a series in powers of $y-1$:

$$ x = 1+2\, \left( y-1 \right) +{\frac {2}{3}} \left( y-1 \right) ^{2}-{
\frac {2}{9}} \left( y-1 \right) ^{3}+{\frac {14}{135}} \left( y-1
 \right) ^{4}-{\frac {22}{405}} \left( y-1 \right) ^{5}+{\frac {82}{
2835}} \left( y-1 \right) ^{6}-{\frac {86}{6075}} \left( y-1 \right) ^
{7}+{\frac {622}{127575}} \left( y-1 \right) ^{8}+{\frac {1438}{
1148175}} \left( y-1 \right) ^{9}-{\frac {1025966}{189448875}} \left( 
y-1 \right) ^{10}+{\frac {32909314}{3978426375}} \left( y-1 \right) ^{
11}-{\frac {1584376606}{155158628625}} \left( y-1 \right) ^{12}+{
\frac {1068478318}{93095177175}} \left( y-1 \right) ^{13}-{\frac {
3415445666}{279285531525}} \left( y-1 \right) ^{14}+{\frac {
87807997126}{6982138288125}} \left( y-1 \right) ^{15}-{\frac {
52325133235058}{4154372281434375}} \left( y-1 \right) ^{16}+{\frac {
153840284803882}{12463116844303125}} \left( y-1 \right) ^{17}-{\frac {
25287193065300454}{2131192980375834375}} \left( y-1 \right) ^{18}+\ldots
$$
which appears to converge for $|y-1| < 1$.

Comment: How did you obtain this series? Thanks.

Comment: @becko I used Maple.  You could get a few terms by hand using [reversion of series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html).

Comment: Ah, you used something like the  `InverseSeries` function of Mathematica (sorry I don't have Maple).