# Finding a value of $a$ to satisfy an expression of the form $a*(1-\frac{1}{b})^{(a-1)} = r$

Tags: approximation

Consider the following expression:

$a*(1-\frac{1}{b})^{(a-1)} = r$

Provided some real number value for $b$, I need to find a positive real number $0 < a \leq b$ to satisfy the above equation, where $0 < r < 1$.

Must we appeal to an approximation for the above expression to solve for $a \leq b$?  If so, what is a good approximation that becomes better as $a \to Inf$?

Comment: Here is [the technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185397/number-to-the-exponent-divided-by-exponent-value/185411#185411) of the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$
\begin{align*}
a\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right)^{a-1} &= r \\
a\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right)^a &= \left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right)r \\
a e^{a \log\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right)} &= \left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right)r \\
a \log\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right) e^{a \log\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right)} &= \left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right)r\log\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right),
\end{align*}
$$

so that

$$
\begin{align*}
a \log\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right) &= W\left(\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right) r \log\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right)\right) \\
a &= \frac{W\left(\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right) r \log\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right)\right)}{\log\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right)},
\end{align*}
$$

where $W$ is the the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).  Note that $W(x)$ is double-valued when $x \in (-1/e,0)$, and the solution you want is given by the principal branch:

$$
a_0 = \frac{W_0\left(\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right) r \log\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right)\right)}{\log\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right)}
$$

If you'd like, you can expand this in a series which converges for $b$ large:

$$
a_0 = r + \frac{r(r-1)}{b} - \frac{3r^2(r-1)}{2b^2} + O(b^{-3}).
$$

Let us denote the other solution, given by the other branch of $W$, by

$$
a_{-1} = \frac{W_{-1}\left(\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right) r \log\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right)\right)}{\log\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right)}.
$$

One can use the asymptotic series derived in this paper [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.112.6117) (pp. 19-23) to calculate an expression for this solution as $b \to \infty$:

$$
a_{-1} = -\frac{1}{\log\!\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right)}\left\{\log b + \log \log b - \log r + \frac{\log \log b}{\log b} - \frac{\log r}{\log b} + O\!\left(\frac{\log \log b}{\log b}\right)^2\right\}.
$$

This is an okay approximation but note that the absolute error does not decrease to $0$ so it won't be very helpful for numerics.

Comment: The derivation seems to be correct, and I find the same thing using WolframAlpha (without your helpful derivation though).  However, I seem to be finding $a \approx r$ using either the Lamber W function or power series approximation.  Is there an obvious mistake I'm making?

Comment: Try any example value for 0 < r < 1

Comment: It is true that $a \approx r$ when $b$ is large.  This isn't the solution you're looking for?  The other solution, given by the other branch of $W$, is larger than $b$.  [See this plot](http://i.imgur.com/VsxhZ.png), with $b$ on the horizontal axis and the other solution, $a^*$, on the vertical axis.

Comment: If you'd like an asymptotic representation for this other solution, see the [wikipedia page for W under "Asymptotic expansions"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Asymptotic_expansions) and use the one for $W_{-1}(x)$.